# How to say "files are in descending order of their names" in Esperanto?

Tags: translation

I was trying to use the word, namely `malkreska` which I learnt from a Japanese dictionary that it would means 'in descending order'.

Can you please help me to construct a sentence? 
My trial:

> La dosieroj ordigis malkreske de siaj nomoj.

Comment: Maybe "estas ord**it**aj" or "ord**it**as" instead of "ord**ig**is"? With "ordigis", I think it'd mean "The files cause being ordered ..." or "The files order / sort ..." and the required direct object would be missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this sentence in Tekstaro:

> [...] mi petis mian 13-jaran filinon listigi la landojn kiujn ŝi
>   vizitis laŭ la malkreska ordo de ŝiaj preferoj (t.e. unue la pli
>   preferindajn).

Following a similar structure you could say:

*La dosieroj **estas ordigitaj**/**ordiĝas** laŭ la malkreska ordo de siaj nomoj*.

*La dosieroj **estas ordigitaj**/**ordiĝas** malkreske de siaj nomoj*.

If you want to be very precise you could write:

*La dosieroj **estas ordigitaj**/**ordiĝas** laŭ la alfabete **malkreska**/**inversa** ordo de siaj nomoj*.

Answer (score 3):

> La dosieroj ordigis malkreske de siaj nomoj.

When I read that sentence, the first thing that comes to my mind is: La dosieroj ordigis **kion**? So I would suggest this, employing the passive voice:

> La dosieroj **estas** ordig**it**aj { malkreske | en malkreska ordo } **laŭ** siaj nomoj.

Answer (score 2):

> La dosieroj estas ordigitaj laŭ malkresk(ant)a nomo.

[Komputeko](https://komputeko.net/index_en.php?vorto=descending) can be one of the sources for computer terms. The many translations in Linux are also normative. Or LibreOffice. (Not everything is perfect though IMHO.)

Comment: Dankon! Mi certe vizitos tiun retejon.

Answer (score 0):

Ĉar mi ofte densigas esprimojn pro la ofte malabunda reteja tereno, mi proponus la jenan:

"Dosieroj malkreske laŭ nomo." aŭ
"Dosieroj ordigitaj malkreske laŭ nomo."